# Not possible to install packages in Ubuntu Bionic Beaver

Tags: texlive, installing, ubuntu

Let's start from scratch:

```
» rm -rf ~/texmf/
» tlmgr init-usertree
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
Cannot determine type of tlpdb from /home/zebra/texmf!
```

What repo do I have?

```
» tlmgr repository list
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Initialization failed (in setup_unix_one):
/usr/bin/tlmgr: could not find a usable xzdec.
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Please install xzdec and try again.
tlmgr: Couldn't set up the necessary programs.
Installation of packages is not supported.
Please report to texlive@tug.org.
tlmgr: Continuing anyway ...
List of repositories (with tags if set):
        http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet (main)
```

It seems something is missing. Let's install it:

```
» sudo apt install xzdec
```

Now it is better:

```
» tlmgr repository list
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
List of repositories (with tags if set):
        http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet (main)
```

Let's install `koma-script`:

```
» tlmgr install koma-script
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018)
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
Please see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

Ok, according to [this page](https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html), the repo should be 2017 (Ubuntu Bionic Beaver has texlive 2017).

It seems there is a problem with Bionic Beaver, because they are using texlive 2017, but nowhere this is configured, and `tex` uses by default the current url (http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet)

This should be easy to fix. Let's specify the url for the right repo:

```
» tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2017/tlnet-final
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: setting default package repository to ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2017/tlnet-final
```

This is now correct:

```
» tlmgr repository list
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
List of repositories (with tags if set):
        ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2017/tlnet-final (main)
```

Let's check what is intalled in the system:

```
» tlmgr list --only-installed
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
```

Nothing!? Strange. Why?? Let's update all packages:

```
» tlmgr update --all
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
```

Nothing happens, runs forever ...

Whatever, let's try to install `koma-script` anyway:

```
» tlmgr install koma-script
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
```

Nothing happens, runs forever ...

So my question is:

How can I instal `koma-script` in an `Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver` system?

Comment: I also used to use TeX Live from the Debian repositories but I found only pain and suffering which is why I switched quite early to [“vanilla” TeX Live](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu).

Comment: Probably best solution: Don't use the TeXLive from the Ubuntu/Debian repositories but upstream's.

Comment: If you want to install a full TeX Live on Ubuntu/Debian, use `sudo apt install texlive-full`

Comment: @HenriMenke too complex ...

Comment: @Skillmon too complex ...

Comment: @HenriMenke it worked! The installed packages are still not listed by `tlmgr` but `koma-script` can be used. Can you put this as answer and I will accept?

Comment: @dangonfast I just learned first hand that using the TeXLive distributions from a Linux repository can lead to problems (and I used the one from Arch Linux which is far less behind than *buntu's) so I turned to use upstreams. It is your decision (and installing it is really easy, just downloading a script, running it and then adding a folder to your $PATH).

Answer (score 4):

To install a full TeX Live system on Debian-based Linux distributions, such as Ubuntu, use

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

However, the TeX Live system included in the repositories is usually quite outdated and doesn't allow for an upgrade beside full-system upgrades.  I recommend removing the distribution-shipped TeX Live system and [installing “vanilla” TeX Live](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/10995) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to the answer of @HenriMenke. If you want a most updated version of TexLive than the officially provided by the Ubuntu package system try the [repository of Jonathon](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive-2019).

Just write on terminal following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive-2019
sudo apt-get update
```

PS: remember that when you access a repository that is not "official", you do it at your own risk. However, I, personally, have no complaint about this one.